# using 13.04 on ancient dell desktop, nvidia geforce 200, worth trying?

Tags: 13.04, nvidia, graphics, dell

I have an ancient Dell Dimension 2400, with an aftermarket Nvidia Geforce 200 graphics card... I installed 13.04 nd the apps seem to work ok but a bit slow, but the desktop is horribly slow, switching windows, opening and closing ubuntu windows all take forever...
I tried downloading the additional drivers, the text in the reviews said "open a terminal and type "$ jockey-kde" but that just got me a command unknown (or whatever)

How can I install the right drivers, or would it be better for me to go back to version 12.04 or 12.10? and if so, how to I make it go back to an earlier version without just performing a full re-install?

thanks

Comment: Use Lubuntu, which is lighter.  12.04 and 12.10 will have similar 'slowness' issues on that machine.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 12.04 has a less resource intensive interface and would be faster, I would also try Lubuntu or Xubuntu which will also be slower, you can install xfce in ubuntu with

```
    $sudo apt-get install xfce
```

Then when you log out, on the login screen there is an icon by your name. Click on it to switch interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use [Lubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/GetLubuntu) instead.  It is a different desktop environment, and should be lighter weight.  It should run more smoothly than Ubuntu.

Comment: well, I started out with ubuntu 11.10 whichI had not run for some time (on a dual boot with win XP) and found it was EOL and started doing updates... 1204 and 12.10 seemed to be fairly ok, 12.10 might have been a bit slow...

is there an easy way to go from normal ubuntu to Lubuntu or do i have to just start from scratch?

Comment: You can install the `lubuntu-desktop` package either through the terminal application or a TTY (such as doing ctrl+alt+f1 and then logging into the terminal session).  Then reboot, and after, at the login screen, choose "LXDE" or "Lubuntu" session (whichever shows up in the session list) at the upper right of the login box.  This won't remove the Ubuntu / Unity stuff, so it'll take up more space on your computer by installing the Lubuntu bundle of applications, but it will give you access to the LXDE environment and related applications.